# array to string with prestodb

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have an AWS Athena (parquet) database that in the Athena console returns:

[image]

.. from the following query:

```
SELECT id, 
TYPEOF(organisations) as type,
cardinality(organisations) as len,
organisations
FROM mydb.tbl;
```

Reading the full table remotely into Python (with awswrangler) is failing because `organisations` is array (sometimes zero length).  I've been trying to convert the `organisaions` field to a string representation of the array (or equivalent json) but nothing I've tried so far works.  Any sugestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about preserving the `organization` and `charoffset` field names, you can cast the array to `JSON` and then format it as `varchar` with [`json_format`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json_format#json_format):

```sql
WITH t(organizations) AS (
   VALUES
        ARRAY[ROW('x', 1), ROW('y', 2)],
        ARRAY[ROW('a', 3), ROW('b', 4)],
        ARRAY[]
)
SELECT json_format(CAST(organizations AS JSON))
FROM t
```

=>

```
       _col0
-------------------
 [["x",1],["y",2]]
 [["a",3],["b",4]]
 []
```

Comment: Yep `json_format(CAST(organizations AS JSON))` works for me! Thanks Martin :)

Comment: I now realise that instead of losing the keys as keys (i.e. but preserved in array), I've lost them entirely.  E.g. `[{type=World City, name=Mumbai, Maharashtra, India, country=IN, adm1=IN16, adm2=70184, latitude=18.975, longitude=72.8258}]`  becomes `[["World City","Mumbai, Maharashtra, India","IN","IN16","70184",18.975,72.8258]]`. Any idea how to preserve keys in the arrays?

Comment: The values will be orderered based on how they appear in the ROW objects, so you could leave it up to the client to derive (e.g., by inspecting the type of the organizations field). There's a long-standing issue to change the behavior of the row->json cast to produce what you're looking for, but it's tricky because it's a backward-incompatible change: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/3536. Also, it may be a long time before it's pulled into Athena.

Comment: OK thanks again Martin. I wonder if there's another method to use then. It seems a rather trivial problem to become a project blocker!

Answer (score 0):

If your array elements can be cast to `varchar`, you can convert the array to string using the `array_join` function, see the docs here

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

For example:

```
WITH t(organizations) AS (
   VALUES
        ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5],
        ARRAY[]
)
SELECT array_join(organizations, ',')
FROM t
```

If your arrays contains more complex elements, you can first use the `transform` function to convert them to varchar "customly" and feed that to the `array_join` function, for example:

```
WITH t(organisations) AS (
   VALUES
        ARRAY[cast(ROW('Police Scotland', 6) as ROW(organisation varchar, charoffset integer))],
        ARRAY[]
)
SELECT '{' || array_join(transform(organisations, x -> '{organisation='||x.organisation||',charoffset='||cast(x.charoffset as varchar)||'}'),',') || '}'
FROM t
```

Comment: Interesting, but very unclear how this is supposed to work, and documentation provides no example. Testing on my array field `array_join(organisations, delimiter = ";", null_replacement = "")` returns `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 9:32: Column 'delimiter' cannot be resolved`. Does this function require mapping?

Comment: `varchar` are specified with single quotes. But indeed, the solution above would work only when the elements of the array can be cast to `varchar`, which doesn't seem to be your case. I've edited the answer.